# firebase authentication persistence in electron

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I'm trying to sign in a user  with `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` but after signing the user and moving to another `BrowserWindow` object and initializing the auth object again with the same firebase app .. the `auth.currentUser` property shows as null.

I tried using the `onAuthStateChanged` observer as following :

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth,(user) => {
    console.log(user)
})
```

and I also tried setting the persistence using `setPersistence` :

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth,(user) => {
  setPersistence(auth,browserLocalPersistence).then(console.log(user))
})
```

both ended up giving me a `null` user